# Using eb cli (v3) from a script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to launch `eb deploy` from a deployment script (so non interactive mode) because it's a hell of a lot easier than using `aws cli`

The issue is: there seems to be no way to choose a default environment during `eb init` (as it used to be in older version with the `-e` option). So if an existing application has several environment, `eb cli` will prompt you to choose an environment (and there is no use to select it)...

Of course you can't do `eb use` or `eb config` before doing `eb cli`, that would be too easy:

```
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".
```

any way to go around this ?

Comment: One of the things `eb init` does is create `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` so you might be able to create the config file manually before running `eb init`. You'd probably need to populate the `branch-defaults` and/or `environment-defaults` sections.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Thank you for the suggestion!